# Why doesn't ORACLE allow consecutive newline characters in commands?

Tags: sql, oracle, language-design, whitespace, sqlplus

I write:

```
CREATE TABLE Person ( 
name CHAR(10),

ssn INTEGER);
```

and save it to a file "a.sql".

If I then run it by typing "@a" in the SQL*Plus command prompt, it will tell me that the line starting with "ssn" is not recognized as a command, and is ignored.

From what I gather, it seems that sqlplus terminates a command if it encounters multiple newline characters in a row.  Is this an accurate statement?  If so, does anyone know if this is necessary/ why it chooses to do this?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I don't know about the why, but a completely blank line terminates a command in SQL*Plus.

Quote from [the SQL*Plus docs](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/A91202_01/901_doc/server.901/a88827/ch24.htm) :

**Ending a SQL Command**:
You can end a SQL command in one of three ways:

- with a semicolon (;)
- with a slash (/) on a line by itself
- with a blank line

You can also change how blank lines are treated with SET SQLBLANKLINES

> **SQLBL[ANKLINES] {ON|OFF}**
>
> Controls whether SQL*Plus allows blank lines within a SQL command or script. ON interprets blank lines and new lines as part of a SQL command or script. OFF, the default value, does not allow blank lines or new lines in a SQL command or script or script.
>
> Enter the BLOCKTERMINATOR to stop SQL command entry without running the SQL command. Enter the SQLTERMINATOR character to stop SQL command entry and run the SQL statement.

Answer (score 5):

By default, SQLPlus does terminate (but not execute) a statement when a blank line is entered. It has always done this. It probably seemed like a good idea in the days before screen editors and query tools.

You can change that default behaviour with

set SQLBLANKLINES on

In which case you'd have to enter a line with just a full stop to terminate (but not execute) a statement.

Answer (score 0):

But if you are wanting to insert multiline text in a varchar2 or a clob field, you may use 
chr(10)

```
 insert into t values ('Hello,'||chr(10)||chr(10)||' How are you?');

 insert into t values (
 'Hello,

 How are you');
```

will not work for reasons explained above.